# How to solve \[Theta]23 from the following equation?

Tags: equation-solving, parametric-functions

How do I solve [Theta]23 from the following equation?

```
eq = 2 Exp[-I δ Degree] Sec[θ12 Degree]^2 (-(1/4) Exp[2 I δ Degree] 
(7 + Cos[8 θ12 Degree]) Cos[θ23 Degree]^2 Sec[2 θ12 Degree]^2 
+ 8 Exp[2 I δ Degree] Cos[δ Degree] Cos[θ12 Degree] 
Cos[θ23 Degree] Sin[θ12 Degree] Sin[θ13 Degree] 
Sin[θ23 Degree] - Sin[θ13 Degree] ((1 + 4 Exp[2 I δ Degree] 
+ 2 Exp[4 I δ Degree] + Cos[4 θ12 Degree]) Sin[θ13 Degree] 
Sin[θ23 Degree]^2 - Exp[I δ Degree] (1 + Exp[2 I δ Degree] - 
2 Cos[2 θ12 Degree]) Sin[2 θ12 Degree] Sin[2 θ23 Degree]))==0
```

Comment: fyi, fixed your input for the Greek letters and changed `=` to `==` and added `eq=`.

Comment: Thank you. But how do I solve theta23 from this equation?

Comment: Would you mind accepting my answer, because it is just that...

Answer (score 2):

You  can help Mathematica a bit .
Express all terms that contain θ23 through an abbreviation variable called s (reminding of the Sin function) to prevent all sorts of trigonometric transformations happening to Sin[θ23 Degree] while trying to solve for it.

```
eq=(2 Exp[-I δ Degree] Sec[θ12 Degree]^2 (-(1/4) Exp[2 I δ Degree] 
(7 + Cos[8 θ12 Degree]) Cos[θ23 Degree]^2 Sec[2 θ12 Degree]^2 
+ 8 Exp[2 I δ Degree] Cos[δ Degree] Cos[θ12 Degree] 
Cos[θ23 Degree] Sin[θ12 Degree] Sin[θ13 Degree] 
Sin[θ23 Degree] - Sin[θ13 Degree] ((1 + 4 Exp[2 I δ Degree] 
+ 2 Exp[4 I δ Degree] + Cos[4 θ12 Degree]) Sin[θ13 Degree] 
Sin[θ23 Degree]^2 - Exp[I δ Degree] (1 + Exp[2 I δ Degree] - 
2 Cos[2 θ12 Degree]) Sin[2 θ12 Degree] Sin[2 θ23 Degree]))
(* in the following the replacement is done *)
/. {Sin[2 θ23 Degree] -> 2 s Sqrt[1 - s^2], (* Sin[2x]=2Sin[x]Cos[x]*)
    Cos[θ23 Degree]^2 -> 1 - s^2, (* Cos[x]^2=1-Sin[x]^2*)
    Cos[θ23 Degree] -> Sqrt[1 - s^2], (* Cos[x]=Sqrt[1-Sin[x]^2]*)
    Sin[θ23 Degree] -> s})
```

Then simply solve for s:

```
Simplify[Solve[eq == 0, s]](* Simplify takes more than 150 seconds *)
```

You get four solutions for s . Find the correct one ...
Apply ArcSin[s]/Degree to get to θ23 . You will have to test numerically whether one or more of the results satisfy the original equation.

Comment: Thank you so much