# How to uniformly distribute data points in all the region in a ListLogLogPlot

Tags: plotting, random

I've drawn a listLogLogPlot by generating random numbers. But the random numbers are not uniformly generated in all the region. More points are generated in the higher region than in the lower side. It will be very helpful if you show how to make the modifications in the code so that the random numbers are equally distributed in all the region. Here is the code that I've written

````
```mee[m1_, \[Beta]_, \[Alpha]_, c12_, c13_, s12_, s13_, m2_,m3_] := \[Sqrt](m1 c12^2 c13^2 + 
  m2 s12^2 s13^2 Cos[2 \[Alpha] Degree] + 
  m3 s12^2 c13^2 Cos[2 \[Beta] Degree])^2 + (m2 s12^2 c13^2 Sin[
   2 \[Alpha] Degree] + m3 s13^2 Sin[2 \[Beta] Degree])^2; ```
````

```
   Tab28 = Table[{m1, 
    mee[m1, Random[Real, {-360 , 360 }], Random[Real, {-360, 360}], 
     Random[Real, {0.851, 0.8062}], Random[Real, {0.9896, 0.9876}], 
     Random[Real, {0.5241, 0.5915}], Random[Real, {0.1438, 0.15695}], 
     Random[Real, {0.0491, 0.05109}], 
     Random[Real, {0.0483, 0.0502}]]}, {m1, 10^-4, 10^0, 
    0.0001 Degree}];
   P28 = ListLogLogPlot[Tab28, PlotRange -> {10^-4, 10^0}, 
  FrameLabel -> {m1, Abs[Subscript[m, ee]]  }, Frame -> True, 
  FrameStyle -> Thick, PlotStyle -> Magenta]
```

Comment: Hello. In your `Table`, try to replace `{m1,10^-4,10^0,0.0001 Degree}` by `{m1,Exp[Range[Log[10^(-4)],Log[10^0],0.00005]]}`. Adjust the number `0.00005` to your needs. Does that answer your question?

Comment: I removed the [tag:graphs-and-networks], as I have from some of your earlier questions before. Please do not add unrelated tags to questions. See the tag description for what the tag is for.

Comment: I looked at your 9 questions on this site and noticed that you never accepted an answer so far. You can accept an answer by clicking on the checkmark next to the answer. (It should then turn green.) For example [this previous question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/256604) has a useful answer, it would be nice if you could officially accept it. You can find a list of all your previous questions [in your profile](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/77403/sangeeta-dey).

Comment: Thank you so much for the suggestion. I was actually not aware of that. I will surely do that. And your answer was very useful. Thanks.